# selenium xpath unable to identify class visually seen in HTML

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to click on the rate button to set the rating for episode one of Atlanta season four on the IMDB website as illustrated by the image further below.

I have tried various combinations of selenium xpath values and have googled various links to attempt to achieve this, but can't remember which now. My current python is below.

```py
driver.get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4288182/episodes/?ref_=tt_ov_epl')

xpath = './/*[@class="list_item odd"]|.//*[@class="list_item even"]'
div = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)

xpath = './/*[@class="ipl-rating-star ipl-rating-interactive__star--empty"]'
div2 = div.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)

selector = "spam>svg>path"
class2 = div2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)
```

The div variable is assigned as I want with a single element; but the python fails to find the attribute value 'ipl-rating-star ipl-rating-interactive__star--empty' , though it can be seen in the html copied from the web page below:

```html
<div class="ipl-rating-star ipl-rating-interactive__star--empty ">
    <span class="ipl-rating-star__star">
        <svg class="ipl-icon ipl-star-border-icon  " xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24">
            <path d="M22 9.24l-7.19-.62L12 2 9.19 8.63 2 9.24l5.46 4.73L5.82 21 12 17.27 18.18 21l-1.63-7.03L22 9.24zM12 15.4l-3.76 2.27 1-4.28-3.32-2.88 4.38-.38L12 6.1l1.71 4.04 4.38.38-3.32 2.88 1 4.28L12 15.4z"></path>
            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
        </svg>
    </span>
    <span class="ipl-rating-star__rating">Rate</span>
</div>
```

The python currently produces this error message: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@class="ipl-rating-star ipl-rating-interactive__star--empty"]"}
(Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.127)

I am also using PyCharm 2022.2.2 Build #PC-222.4167.33 with Python 3.10.7

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong locators.
Also you need to add delays to wait for elements to become clickable.
The best practice here is to use `WebDriverWait` expected conditions explicit waits.
The following code is working.
It actually contains only 2 clicks.
I'm selecting the rating **6** here, but you can select any other value as well.
This can also be done with CSS Selectors instead of XPath.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")


webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
url = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4288182/episodes/?ref_=tt_ov_epl"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'ipl-rating-interactive__star--')]//span[@class='ipl-rating-star__rating']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='#void'][@data-value='6']//div[contains(@class,'ipl-rating-interactive__star--')]//span"))).click()
```

After these to clicks you need to login in order to perform rating
[image]