# How do I locate text using xpath?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have been asked to improve my questions. I'm autistic; so I'm unable to lie. I did research the internet and actually couldn't remember where I'd been on the internet as I wrote below; but on this question I realised I could comb through my internet history; so will do a better job of listing the pages I visit before posting a question.

I posted a question in a comment and then immediately saw the answerer fixing the question; so I assumed that they hadn't seen my comment and deleted it. I later saw that the answerer had actually responded to my comment; so I will get into the practise of not deleting anything going forward.

I will resume contributing to the site too. I am consumed with my projects at the moment.

I spent a solid eight hours banging my head against this problem, before I asked it as a question here. This was asked 14 hours after a previous question; so the automatic bot might have thought I was asking questions too frequently; so I will remember to wait days before asking further questions.

### Original question below

I am trying to click on the Inclusive button within my account on the IMDB website as illustrated by the image further below.

I have tried various combinations of selenium xpath values and have googled various links to attempt to achieve this including [this](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/xpath-writing-cheat-sheet-tutorial-examples/). My current python is below less logging onto the IMDB website to be able to effect this change.

```py
driver.get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt14772170/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# click on arrow button in bottom right hand corner of image further below
#  to call up pop-up window wth lists like Inclusive
xpath = "//button[@class='ipc-split-button__iconBtn']"
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))).click()

try:
    match_found = True
    xpath = "//div[@class='sc-1aecbe70-0 dpbfLr']/div[@data-titleinlist='false']"
    button1 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath)
    xpath = "//*[contains(text(), 'Inclusive')]"
    button2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
    xpath = "//div[@class='sc-1aecbe70-0 dpbfLr']/div[@data-titleinlist='false']/*[contains(text(), 'Inclusive')]"
    button3 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button3)
except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
    match_found = False
```

Buttons 1 and 2 work as I want illustrating that the actual xpath I need for button3 should work too. Buttons 1 and 2 will not be needed in the final code and are there only to illustrate that they at least work separately. An example of the HTML I'm trying to scrape is below:

```html
<div class="sc-1aecbe70-0 dpbfLr">
    <div role="button" tabindex="0" data-titleinlist="false" class="sc-1aecbe70-1 fkjUqe">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" class="ipc-icon ipc-icon--add sc-1aecbe70-2 csaBFR" id="iconContext-add" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" role="presentation">
            <path d="M18 13h-5v5c0 .55-.45 1-1 1s-1-.45-1-1v-5H6c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1s.45-1 1-1h5V6c0-.55.45-1 1-1s1 .45 1 1v5h5c.55 0 1 .45 1 1s-.45 1-1 1z"></path>
        </svg>
    Inclusive</div>
    <a href="/list/ls560615425/?ref_=tt_ov_ls_menu_sm" aria-label="Go to list: Inclusive" class="sc-1aecbe70-4 grpYsz">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" class="ipc-icon ipc-icon--chevron-right" id="iconContext-chevron-right" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" role="presentation">
            <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z"></path><path d="M9.29 6.71a.996.996 0 0 0 0 1.41L13.17 12l-3.88 3.88a.996.996 0 1 0 1.41 1.41l4.59-4.59a.996.996 0 0 0 0-1.41L10.7 6.7c-.38-.38-1.02-.38-1.41.01z"></path>
        </svg>
    </a>
</div>
```

The python currently produces no error message but jumps from button3 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath) to the except clause

I am using PyCharm 2022.2.2 Build #PC-222.4167.33 with Python 3.10.7 and chromedriver win32 105.0.5195.52

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73780643/selenium-xpath-unable-to-identify-click-on-web-page) before; but that was pertaining to rating a show, which has a completely different setup of HTML

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `xpath` seems wrong. Use the below `xpath` to click on the `Inclusive` button

```
//div[@role='button' and @data-titleinlist='false'][contains(., 'Inclusive')]
```

So your code will be like

```
xpath = "//div[@role='button' and @data-titleinlist='false'][contains(., 'Inclusive')]"
button3 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button3)
```

Please provide enough wait to element to be visible or clickable.

you can use below `xpath` as well.

```
//div[@class='sc-1aecbe70-0 dpbfLr']//div[@role='button'][contains(., 'Inclusive')]
```

You can use that as well.

```
//div[@class='sc-1aecbe70-0 dpbfLr']//div[@role='button' and @data-titleinlist='false'][contains(., 'Inclusive')]
```

Comment: 20 means 20 seconds. That is enough I believe. I have updated the mandatory attribute as well, try now.